# Stop the footer from showing in my about page?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to have it so that my website does not show the footer on the home page (aka the front page) and the about page. This is the `if` statement I have so far:

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page()):  ?>
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'sylvieshimmy' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'sylvieshimmy' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'sylvieshimmy' ), 'Sylvieshimmy', '<a href="http://underscores.me/" rel="designer">Underscores.me</a>' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I make it so that the footer does not show up on the about page as well? So far this only works for the front page. My about page template is saved as 'page-about.php'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make use of `is_page()` or `is_page_template` conditional tags

Example

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() && !is_page_template('page-about.php)):  ?>
```

Or

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() && !is_page('name_of_about_page)):  ?>
```